# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] - AngularJS module issue

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I apologize if this issue has been resolved somewhere, but every other question I looked at with a similar name was unable to resolve my problem. I have a plunker with a barebones layout of a web app I am working on, but for some reason am receiving an `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]` when I try to run it.

I have attached the Plunk below, hopefully someone can point out what the issue is, because I cannot find it. I am using ui-router and ui-bootstrap with twitter-bootstrap styling.

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/EbGJAqxdjHRCMjjC6waA?p=info

(Never shared a plunk before, so hopefully I did it correctly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didnt include your app file in the script srcs

[forked plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iS3jjwX90iq500hZOsqJ?p=preview)

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! Sorry about the comment, not sure why it wasn't working initially after adding the tag, but I got it working eventually. Thanks for the fork!

Answer (score 1):

You are never including your `app.js` file, so your Angular module is never actually defined.

I tried adding this line to your plunk and it worked fine.

```
 <script src="app.js"></script>
```